Mininal ISO Ubuntu Files
I want a minimal Ubuntu to install Because I only have 25GB of Free space left, and I need it.

The minimal ISO exists so it can be written to mini-CD install media (eg. a noble or 24.04 ISO can be found here - https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mini-iso/noble/daily-live/current/).  The tiny minimal ISO at 89MB doesn't mean the install is any smaller; it's just contains the minimum require to boot & start install (rest being downloaded at install time).  You don't specify what Ubuntu product you want to download; 25GB is plenty for many server installs; but it's minimum for a desktop install

This question is similar to: What is the difference between Ubuntu 24.04 Default (minimal) installation and Full installation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

25GB is a lot more than minimal.
